# Get Timestamp difference in ksql

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-cloud

I need to calculate the difference of the two timestamp in KSQL confluent.cloud.

Below are my queries,

```
SELECT
  ENTITY -> IENTITYID,
  ENTITY -> DTINSERTDATE,
  ENTITY -> DTUPDATEDATE, 
  HEADERS -> OPERATION,
  TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(ROWTIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') AS rowtime_formatted,
  CAST(ENTITY -> DTUPDATEDATE AS TIMESTAMP) AS UpdatedDateFROMtblEntity
FROM tblEntity
EMIT CHANGES
LIMIT 10;
```

Here, I have two timestamp such as ROWTIME and UpdatedDateFROMtblEntity. So, how to calculate the difference on those timestamps?. I need this in milliseconds. Please help me to resolve this issues.

Comment: Hope this helps you to get an idea, I have made difference with epoc value converted into milliseconds by dividing into 1000  cast(DTUPDATEDATE as BIGINT)-CAST( rowtime AS BIGINT))/1000)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(col1) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(col2) 
FROM STREAM1 EMIT CHANGES;
```

Reference: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/scalar-functions/#unix_timestamp

Comment: Code and a link do not count as an answer according to [answer]. An explanation directly here is expected.